# Mongo update field in array based on index

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, angular-meteor

I have a collection of projects (`Projects`)with a record `project` which has an array `equipInfo`, lets say I wanted to update the quantity of index 1 in array:

```
"techInfo" : {    
    "equipInfo" : [ 
                {
                    "item" : {
                        "$ref" : "equipment",
                        "$id" : ObjectId("581a20cb4abab607fd17f07d")
                    },
                    "quantity" : "22800",
                    "type" : "module"
                }, 
                {
                    "item" : {
                        "$ref" : "equipment",
                        "$id" : ObjectId("581a20cb4abab607fd17f07e")
                    },
                    "quantity" : "1666",   <===== UPDATE THIS!!!!!!
                    "type" : "inverter"
                }
        ]
}
```

So I tried:

```
    Projects.update(
        {_id: projectId},
        {$set: {"techInfo.equipInfo.1.quantity": 1000000}
    );
```

But this doesn't work, I'm using Meteor.js btw

Comment: Use 0 {$set: {"techInfo.equipInfo.1.quantity": 1000000} Check my answer

Comment: Did you try it on the client or on the server? Did you get an error? A different result than you were expecting? As others have mentioned, your statement does not even compile (syntax error).

Comment: Is this a bogus question? It looks like the code in the accepted answer matches your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "this doesn't work"?  Is there an error?

The following works as expected, as /server/main.js in a new meteor project:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo  } from 'meteor/mongo'

Projects = new Mongo.Collection("projects");

Meteor.startup(() => {
    Projects.remove({})
    Projects.insert( {
        "techInfo": {
            "equipInfo": [{
                    "item": {
                        "$ref": "equipment",
                        "$id": new Mongo.ObjectID("581a20cb4abab607fd17f07d")
                    },
                    "quantity": "22800",
                    "type": "module"
                },
                {
                    "item": {
                        "$ref": "equipment",
                        "$id": new Mongo.ObjectID("581a20cb4abab607fd17f07e")
                    },
                    "quantity": "1666",
                    "type": "inverter"
                }
            ]
        }
    } )
    let techInfo = Projects.findOne();
    Projects.update({ _id: techInfo._id }, 
      { $set: { "techInfo.equipInfo.1.quantity": 1000000 } }
    );
    console.log(Projects.findOne().techInfo);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:

```
Projects.update(
    {_id: projectId},
    {$set: {"techInfo.equipInfo.1.quantity": 1000000}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update the first object of the array not depending on condition this is your solution

```
Projects.update({_id: projectId},{$set : {"techInfo.equipInfo.0.quantity" : 1000000}})
```

If you want to traverse through the element find the array and update that,You can use this

```
Projects.update({_id: projectId,"techInfo.equipInfo" : {"$elemMatch" : {"type" : "module"}}},{$set : {"techInfo.equipInfo.$.quantity" : 1000000}})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, The `{` before `$set` needs to be closed

```
Projects.update(
    {_id: projectId},
    {$set: {"techInfo.equipInfo.1.quantity": 1000000}}
);
```